# transform json to polars dataframe

Tags: json, python-polars

i have the following json file and i would like to transform to a dataframe Polars. How can I use the pl.read_json function that have schema attribute?

```
    {
        "data": {
            "names": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E"
            ],
            "ndarray": [
                [
                    "abc",
                    true,
                    0.374618,
                    1,
                    0.83252
                ],
                [
                    "hello",
                    false,
                    0.1265374619,
                    0,
                    0.253
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use `pl.read_json` with a file structured in that way.

The issue is `ndarray` contains "mixed types" which is not allowed in Polars.

```json
[
    "abc",      # str
    true,       # bool
    0.374618,   # float
    1,          # int
    0.83252     # float
]
```

Polars must choose a single type, e.g. in this case `str` is chosen as the "supertype":

```py
pl.select(pl.lit("""["abc", true, 1.23]""").str.json_decode())
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────────────┐
│ literal                 │
│ ---                     │
│ list[str]               │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ ["abc", "true", "1.23"] │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

And there's no way to access the "original" type information.

If you load the JSON first, outside of Polars (e.g. using the `json` module) you can use `pl.DataFrame()` directly.

```py
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)["data"]
    df = pl.DataFrame(data["ndarray"], schema=data["names"])
```

```py
shape: (2, 5)
┌───────┬───────┬──────────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ A     ┆ B     ┆ C        ┆ D   ┆ E       │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ str   ┆ bool  ┆ f64      ┆ i64 ┆ f64     │
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ abc   ┆ true  ┆ 0.374618 ┆ 1   ┆ 0.83252 │
│ hello ┆ false ┆ 0.126537 ┆ 0   ┆ 0.253   │
└───────┴───────┴──────────┴─────┴─────────┘
```