# Transform JSON Key into a Polars DataFrame

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I was wondering how to read in a JSON file into a polars DataFrame in Rust on the "data" key. However, I believe the structure of the JSON file that I have would be hard to achieve.

Here is the first Structure of the JSON File where it contains dataTypes.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dataItemName": "TICKER",
      "result": [
        "AAPL",
        "MSFT",
        "TSLA"
      ],
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "SALES",
      "result": [ 
        259968,
        143015,
        24578
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "CNAME",
      "result": [
        "Apple Inc.",
        "Microsoft Corporation",
        "Tesla Inc"
      ],
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "PRICE",
      "result": [
        115.98,
        214.22,
        430.83
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "ASSETS",
      "result": [
        338516,
        301311,
        34309
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I have tried in Rust.

```
use polars::prelude::*;


fn main() {
    let json_file = std::fs::File::open("data/test_merged.json").unwrap();
    let df = JsonReader::new(json_file).finish().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", df);
}
```

Here is the Rust output example which single column/row DataFrame

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ data                              │
│ ---                               │
│ list[struct[63]]                  │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{0.0,0.530558,3.38631,"2023-06-… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

There are only 3 Data Types Which are Stings Floats and Integers.

Here is a similar question for a Python Version.
[transform json to polars dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77461175/transform-json-to-polars-dataframe)

Comment: Are you sure you want the dataframe to be like Python does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is important, then @BallpointBen's version is not the fastest you can get; here's a more performant version:

```rust
pub fn convert(json: &str) -> Result<DataFrame, Box<dyn Error>> {
    use serde::Deserialize;

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum Values {
        String(Vec<String>),
        Double(Vec<f64>),
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(rename_all = "UPPERCASE")]
    enum DataType {
        String,
        Double,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
    struct Column {
        data_item_name: String,
        result: Values,
        data_type: DataType,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    struct Data {
        data: Vec<Column>,
    }

    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Data>(json)?;
    let df = data
        .data
        .into_iter()
        .map(|column| match column.data_type {
            DataType::String => {
                let Values::String(values) = column.result else {
                    return Err("column type mismatch");
                };
                Ok(Series::new(&column.data_item_name, values))
            }
            DataType::Double => {
                let Values::Double(values) = column.result else {
                    return Err("column type mismatch");
                };
                Ok(Series::from_vec(&column.data_item_name, values))
            }
        })
        .collect::<Result<DataFrame, _>>()?;

    Ok(df)
}
```

Benchmark with 1,000 random entries:

```
BallpointBen            time:   [338.41 µs 340.05 µs 341.85 µs]
Found 2 outliers among 100 measurements (2.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild

Mine                    time:   [195.82 µs 196.79 µs 197.95 µs]
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  8 (8.00%) high mild
  3 (3.00%) high severe
```

Comment: Thank you! Chayim. I will try this one out also.

Comment: I'm surprised that round tripping though `serde_json::Value` is even competitive with your solution (if you consider within 2x the time competitive).

Answer (score 1):

First you should note that 1. in your Python code, Polars is not reading from json, but rather reading from an already-instantiated in-memory dict created from that json 2. the resulting df is almost surely not what you want.

Polars does support serde, but it has its own format, so it's not as simple as just massaging the incoming data. The easiest way is probably to create structs mimicking the structure that Polars expects and implementing all the necessary renaming of fields, then deserializing to make the renaming happen, re-serializing with the renamed fields, and then deserializing again into a `DataFrame`. The code below requires crates `polars` with feature `serde` enabled, `serde`, and `serde_json`.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Values {
    String(Vec<String>),
    Double(Vec<f64>),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum DataType {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "STRING", serialize = "Utf8"))]
    String,
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "DOUBLE"))]
    Float64,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Column {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "dataItemName"))]
    name: String,
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "result"))]
    values: Values,
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "dataType"))]
    datatype: DataType,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Data {
    #[serde(rename(deserialize = "data"))]
    columns: Vec<Column>,
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Data>(DATA)?;
    let df = serde_json::from_value::<DataFrame>(serde_json::to_value(data)?)?;
    println!("{df:?}");

    Ok(())
}
```

The result is

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬──────────┬───────────────────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ TICKER ┆ SALES    ┆ CNAME                 ┆ PRICE  ┆ ASSETS   │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---                   ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str    ┆ f64      ┆ str                   ┆ f64    ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ AAPL   ┆ 259968.0 ┆ Apple Inc.            ┆ 115.98 ┆ 338516.0 │
│ MSFT   ┆ 143015.0 ┆ Microsoft Corporation ┆ 214.22 ┆ 301311.0 │
│ TSLA   ┆ 24578.0  ┆ Tesla Inc             ┆ 430.83 ┆ 34309.0  │
└────────┴──────────┴───────────────────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

Of course, `DATA` is the string you provided,

```rust
const DATA: &str = r#"
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dataItemName": "TICKER",
      "result": [
        "AAPL",
        "MSFT",
        "TSLA"
      ],
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "SALES",
      "result": [
        259968,
        143015,
        24578
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "CNAME",
      "result": [
        "Apple Inc.",
        "Microsoft Corporation",
        "Tesla Inc"
      ],
      "dataType": "STRING",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "PRICE",
      "result": [
        115.98,
        214.22,
        430.83
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    },
    {
      "dataItemName": "ASSETS",
      "result": [
        338516,
        301311,
        34309
      ],
      "dataType": "DOUBLE",
      "error": 0
    }
  ]
}
"#;
```

Comment: This dataframe is not the same as the Python code returns.

Comment: There is no way that the DataFrame returned by python is what OP actually wants.

Comment: Thanks you! @BallpointBen

This is very helpful. 
And the Dataframe returned in my example is from Rust not Python. And you are correct that I don't want it to be a single column/row with the list passed as the single datapoint.

Comment: @TrevorSeibert As recommended by polars, if you use this answer consider switching the allocator to something like [jemalloc](https://docs.rs/jemallocator) or [mimalloc](https://docs.rs/mimalloc), this improves the performance of this code significantly (this also significantly improves my first answer, but not the second, probably because it doesn't allocate a lot).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you for the examples! I also have one last question I added above. How would you suggest creating a DF with a Flattened JSON format?

Comment: @TrevorSeibert This is a separate question and it should be asked as a separate SO question (don't forget to accept some answer that helped you). Do you have two different JSON files?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, I have two different JSON files where the other one is a fattened format, but same kind of data.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I will go ahead and ask this in a seperate SO question.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON is self-describing, i.e. it has no two data types represented with the same JSON type (for example, dates and strings represented as strings) - in other words, the `dataType` field is redundant, then the absolute fastest way is to deserialize directly into `Series`:

```rust
pub fn directly_into_series(json: &str) -> Result<DataFrame, Box<dyn Error>> {
    use serde::de::{DeserializeSeed, Deserializer, Error, SeqAccess, Visitor};
    use serde::Deserialize;

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
    struct Column {
        data_item_name: String,
        #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_values")]
        result: Series,
    }

    fn deserialize_values<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Series, D::Error> {
        struct Builders {
            strings: StringChunkedBuilder,
            floats: PrimitiveChunkedBuilder<Float64Type>,
            has_strings: bool,
            has_floats: bool,
        }
        impl Default for Builders {
            fn default() -> Self {
                Self {
                    strings: StringChunkedBuilder::new("", 0),
                    floats: PrimitiveChunkedBuilder::new("", 0),
                    has_strings: false,
                    has_floats: false,
                }
            }
        }

        struct ElementDeserializer<'a>(&'a mut Builders);

        impl<'de, 'a> DeserializeSeed<'de> for ElementDeserializer<'a> {
            type Value = ();

            fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                deserializer.deserialize_any(self)
            }
        }

        impl<'de, 'a> Visitor<'de> for ElementDeserializer<'a> {
            type Value = ();

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(formatter, "expected a float or string")
            }

            fn visit_str<E>(self, v: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: Error,
            {
                self.0.strings.append_value(v);
                self.0.has_strings = true;
                Ok(())
            }

            fn visit_f64<E>(self, v: f64) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: Error,
            {
                self.0.floats.append_value(v);
                self.0.has_floats = true;
                Ok(())
            }
        }

        struct SeqVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for SeqVisitor {
            type Value = Series;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(formatter, "expected a sequence of floats or strings")
            }

            fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut builders = Builders::default();
                while let Some(()) = seq.next_element_seed(ElementDeserializer(&mut builders))? {}

                match (builders.has_strings, builders.has_floats) {
                    (false, false) | (true, false) => Ok(builders.strings.finish().into_series()),
                    (false, true) => Ok(builders.floats.finish().into_series()),
                    (true, true) => Err(A::Error::custom("sequence with both floats and strings")),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_seq(SeqVisitor)
    }

    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    struct Data {
        data: Vec<Column>,
    }

    let data = serde_json::from_str::<Data>(json)?;
    let df = data
        .data
        .into_iter()
        .map(|mut column| {
            column.result.rename(&column.data_item_name);
            column.result
        })
        .collect::<DataFrame>();

    Ok(df)
}
```

Benchmark with random 10,000 entries:

```
BallpointBen            time:   [3.2342 ms 3.2510 ms 3.2692 ms]
Found 2 outliers among 100 measurements (2.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild

Benchmarking Mine (other answer): Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 9.5s, enable flat sampling, or reduce sample count to 50.
Mine (other answer)     time:   [1.8601 ms 1.8670 ms 1.8745 ms]
Found 6 outliers among 100 measurements (6.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild
  4 (4.00%) high severe

Deserialize directly into `Series`
                        time:   [739.58 µs 741.60 µs 743.79 µs]
Found 1 outliers among 100 measurements (1.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high severe
```